# Get all the characters until a new date/hour is found

Tags: regex, parsing, multiline

I have to parse a lot of content with a regular expression.
The content might, for example, be:

```
14-08-2015 14:18 : Example : Hello =) How are you?
What are you doing?
14-08-2015 14:19: Example2 : I'm fine thanks!
```

I have this regular expression that will of course return 2 matches, and the groups that I need - data, hour, name, multi line message:

```
(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\s?(\d{2}:\d{2})\s?:([^:]+):([^\d]+)
```

The problem is that if a number is written inside the message this will not be OK, because the regex will stop getting more characters. 
For example in this case this will not work:

```
14-08-2015 14:18 : Example : Hello =) How are you?
What are you 2 doing?
14-08-2015 14:19: Example2 : I'm fine thanks!
```

How do I get all the characters until a new date/hour is found?

Comment: What OS/program are you using the regex in?

Comment: Just trying in http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lookahead for dates and get everything up to that.

```
/^(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\s?(\d{2}:\d{2})\s?:([^:]+):\s?((?:(?!^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s?\d{2}:\d{2}).)*)/sm
```

I've edited you regex in two ways:

1. Added `^`to the front, ensuring you only start from timestamps on their own line, which should filter out most issues with people posting timestamps
2. Replaced the last capturing group with `((?:(?!^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s?\d{2}:\d{2}).)*)`

   - `(?!^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s?\d{2}:\d{2})` is a negative lookahead, with date
   - `(?:(lookahead).)*` Looks for any amount of characters that aren't followed by a date anchored to the start of a line.
   - `((?:(lookahead).)*)` Just captures the group for you.

It's not that efficient, but it works. Note the `s` flag for dotall (dot matches newlines) and `m` flag that lets `^` match at the start of line. `^` is necessary in the lookahead so that you don't stop the match in case someone posts a timestamp, and in the start to make sure you only match dates from the start of a line.

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/rX8eH0/3
DEMO with flags in regex: https://regex101.com/r/rX8eH0/4

Comment: Thank you! This really work! but do you thing that exists any way to do it without the s flag?

Comment: @Sandrita you can use `[\S\s]` instead of `.`

Comment: You could replace the `.` with `[\s\S]` like @AR7 did, but the flag can be included in the regex in most flavors as well. Just put (?sm) before the regex. In any case you need a flag to sort out the dates inside messages.

Comment: @Sandrita I updated the post with an example of flags inside the regex.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your final capturing group `([^\d]+)`.

Instead you can use `((?:(?!\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})[\s\S])+)`

The outer parenthesis: **(**(?:(?!\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})[\s\S])+**)** indicate a capturing group

The next set of parenthesis: (**(?**:(?!\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})[\s\S]**)+**) indicate a non-capturing group that we want to match 1 to infinite amount of times.

Inside we have a negative look ahead: ((?:**(?!\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})**[\s\S])+). This says that whatever we are matching cannot include a date.

What we actually capture: ((?:(?!\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})**[\s\S]**)+) means we capture every character including a new line.

The entire regex that works looks like this:

`(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\s?(\d{2}:\d{2})\s?:([^:]+):((?:(?!\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})[\s\S])+)`

https://regex101.com/r/wH5xR2/2

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) it really helps me!